# Huffman tree string representation

Tags: java, recursion, tree, huffman-code

I need to make a String Representation of a Huffman Tree.
It uses pre-order traversal and the output will produce a String using 'I' (for interior node) and 'L' (for leaf node) followed by the leaf node character.

```
public static String getTreeString(final BinaryNodeInterface<Character> root)
{               
            String treeString="";
            if(root == null)
                return "";
            if(root.isLeaf())
                treeString = treeString + "L" + root.getData();
            else
            {
                treeString = treeString + "I";
                getTreeString(root.getLeftChild());
                getTreeString(root.getRightChild());
            }

            return treeString;

}
```

When I debug the program it goes through and creates the right String but it cannot be saved due to the `String treeString="";` at the beginning of the method.

Desired output: `IIILaILbILcLdLe`

My output: `I`

Also, I am not allowed to use any global/instance variables or any Java pre-defined classes.

Answer (score 3):

The following code:

```
getTreeString(root.getLeftChild());
getTreeString(root.getRightChild());
```

should be

```
treeString += getTreeString(root.getLeftChild());
treeString += getTreeString(root.getRightChild());
```

You do not append your results to treeString.

Comment: No problem ^.^ I am so bad a phrasing answers.